# Showing and hiding SettingsFragment in an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-settings

So I followed [this guide on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment). They suggest to use fragments for showing settings to user.

I created the xml and strings and the fragment:

```
public class SettingsFragmentApp extends PreferenceFragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_app);
    }
}
```

I want to show this on my MainActivity page without creating another activity that only hosts this fragment (I think the later optioon recommended by google kills the point...why should I create another activity for just a fragment?). So I added an option to the `MENU` and I handle it like this in the `MainActivity`:

```
        //inside onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        case (R.id.action_settings_user):
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                    new SettingsFragmentUser()).commit();
            return true;
```

This way the setting fragments shows up as expected, but as soon as user hits back button the application exits because it was still on `MainActivity`.

So the question is how can I handle the back button in such a way that it saves the settings changes and brings back user to the MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want back button functionality you have to add the `Fragment` to the back stack in the transaction.

```
FragmentManager manger = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // Add fragment to back stack.
transaction.commit();
```

But this is not recommended. The reason they suggest you use an extra `Activity` is so you can build the navigation stack with `Activities` instead of fragments. Building a navigation stack with `Fragments` can become problematic very quickly. `Activities` are just supposed to be container for `Fragments`. As such in any app you are going to have many `Activities` that do not contain anything aside from a `Fragment` and these `Activities` are just used to build a navigation stack. In really big apps I tend to write one abstract base `Activity` that implements all the base features you need and reuse this on `Activity` as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks so you mean If I have many different settings fragments, I can handle them all with only one Activity? If so can you share that derived Activity code?

Comment: What I mean is you should not add `Fragments` to the back stack but instead just create an `Activity` for each level in the navigation hierarchy of your app. For content on the same level you can use `FragmentTransactions`. For example in your case I would create a `SettingsActivity`. When somebody clicks on the settings option in your app you open this `SettingsActivity` and display the settings in this `Activity` in a `Fragment`. If you have multiple pages of settings you page through those in this `Activity` using multiple `Fragments`.

Comment: But if you have an additional detail view you would create an additional `Activity`. The rule is if you go deeper inside the hierarchy you use need another `Activity` if you stay on the same level you need another `Fragment`.